# javascript stoppropagation doesn't work with ajax .load

Tags: javascript, jquery, stoppropagation

I used `.stopPropagataion()` to stop the bubbling in `<li class="article">` when clicking on the `<a>` tag.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".article a").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
   });
});
```

With this HTML:

```
<li class="article" onlick="javascript:somefunction();">
   <div id="div_id">
      <a>Some link</a>
   </div>
</li>
```

Everything worked fine, but then I used `$('#div_id').load("div_html.html")` to load some content into the div dynamically. Now my `.stopPropagation()` doesn't stop the bubbling. Why isn't it working anymore?

Comment: try `return false;` instead of `e.stopPropagation();`

Comment: Re `onlick="javascript:somefunction();"`, three issues: 1) It's `onclick`, not `onlick` (you're missing the `c`), and 2) You don't use the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol on event handler attributes, only `href`s; 3) It's best to avoid mixing old-style DOM0 handlers (event handler attributes) with new-style DOM2 code (your handler attached with jQuery).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that when you update the content of the `div`, you destroy all of the elements that were inside it (including any event handlers attached to them). Your code is hooking the `click` event on the `a` elements that are in the `div` **as of when your code runs**; new `a` elements in the `div` will not be hooked up.

In your case, you're better off using [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) ([live example, with `load`](http://jsbin.com/abizew/2)):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".article div").delegate("a", "click", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
   });
});
```

That hooks `click` on the `div` instead. When the click occurs, it bubbles from the link to the `div`, where the click handler created by jQuery examines it to see if it was actually a click on any `a` element. If so, it stops the click.

As of jQuery 1.7, the new recommended syntax is [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".article div").on("click", "a", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
   });
});
```

Note that the order of arguments is different from `delegate`, but other than that it does the same thing.

---

I'd recommend avoiding combining old-style DOM0 handlers (event handler attributes) with new-style DOM2 code (your handler attached with jQuery). In many browsers, the two mechanisms are somewhat separate and may not play as nicely together as you'd like.

Two other comments on this:

```
onlick="javascript:somefunction();"
```

1. It's `onclick`, not `onlick` (you're missing the `c`)
2. You don't use the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol on event handler attributes, only `href`s. Just remove that part. (Why doesn't it cause an error? Because *purely by coincidence*, it's valid JavaScript — you're defining a [label](http://es5.github.com/#x12.12) you never use.)

Comment: Are you sure that works? The click handler is executed when it has bubbled up to `.article`, because it has been attached to that element, so it does not prevent the event from bubbling up to `.article` because it is too late. http://jsfiddle.net/3vHty/

Comment: @pimvdb: Thanks, I realized that as I was adding links, so I moved it to the `div` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and help. 1) It still doesn't work. 2)Regarding onlick (obviously I misspelled, thanks for pointing that up), 3)What do you recommend instead of onclick="javascript:

Comment: @user1073201: 1) It does work barring something outside the code you've quoted; see the updated example in the answer (I added a `load` call). 3) Use jQuery to hook the `click` event on the `li` rather than using `onclick`.

Comment: Your example convinced me that it should work. I will be inspecting my code. Thanks, you made my day.

Comment: @user1073201: Pleasure, glad to help.